# Can't import subpackage into another subpackage

Tags: java, java-package

I am trying to create a package named `myUtil`, inside I have two subpackages named `Node` and `BinaryTree`.

Inside `Node` dir, I have `Node.java` and `Node.class`, and of course the first line in the java file is:

```
package myUtil.Node;
```

Now, in `BinaryTree.java`, located in `BinaryTree` directory, I would like to import `Node.class` to use it.
This is the code:

```
package myUtil.BinaryTree;

import myUtil.Node.Node;

public class BinaryTree {
    public Node root;
}
```

When I try to compile it, it gives me this error:

```
BinaryTree.java:3: error: package myUtil.Node does not exist
import myUtil.Node.Node;
                  ^
```

Also, I tried

```
import myUtil.Node;
import myUtil.Node.*;
```

but it still gives me this error...

Edit: As requested, I'm sharing the whole code.

This is Node.java:

```
package myUtil.Node;

public class Node {
    int value;
    Node left, right;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

And this is BinaryTree.java:

```
package myUtil.BinaryTree;

import myUtil.Node.Node;

public class BinaryTree {
    public Node root;
}
```

I'm compiling these files directly in their respective folders, using:

```
javac filename.java
```

Comment: First of all, take care of java naming conventions. package names should be lower case, Second please share full code of both classes

Comment: Also, share how you are trying to compile it. An IDE? Maven? Gradle? javac? What directory do you run the command from, with what parameters?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited my question.

Comment: You can't compile myUtil.BinaryTree.BinaryTree.java from inside that directory. cd out to the parent directory and run `javac myUtil/BinaryTree/BinaryTree.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't support "sub"-packages. Even if packages are organized as in `java`, `java.net`, `java.util`, each of them is an individual package - although on the disk packages are organized as folders and subfolders.

And you don't `import` packages but only classes or methods.

So in your description, to use the class `Node` from the package `myUtil.Node` in another package, you would need to `import myUtil.Node.Node;`

If you want to use `Node` in a class within the same package (same folder on disk), you don't need to import that.

An import like `import myUtil.Node.*;` imports all classes of the `myUtil.Node` package, but none of any package that starts with `myUtil.Node.` (what you mentioned as "sub"-package). Java doesn't support such imports (like from a folder and all subfolders).

To your specific situation:
Java has a naming convention to use only lowercase letters in package names - convention means, you don't have to do it like that, but it is better if you do because other developers will understand your code faster. (And also we on StackOverflow can help better for you next questions ;-)

Also not every class has to be put into a separate package.

So for you, probably a package `myutils` with the two classes `Node` and `BinaryTree` would be fine - and you don't have to import `Node` into `BinaryTree` then, as they would be both contained in the same package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as you probably noticed I have not understood properly Java packages but this is very helpful! :)

Comment: Here you find an old but still valid tutorial about Java packages: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html (and next to it other tutorials, to get the basics of Java probably OK, but they were written for Java 8, keep that in mind.)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer that @cyberbrain did. I would just add this workflow. Since you are using command prompt.
Assume like you have two separate packages in the same folder:
myUtils.Node and myUtils.BinaryTree

it would compile if you navigate back to the directory where myUtils or where both packages are placed and then compile it such as:
javac myUtils\BinaryTree\BinaryTree.java

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I was looking for this :)

Comment: Glad it helped! You're Welcome!! :)